# Error to register Unity in DependencyResolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

Error:

**The type Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator.**

I saw this question **[WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver does not implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator. Parameter : commonServiceLocator](http://goo.gl/4lEH2)** but my error is in this line:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

the complete class:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container)); // <-- error
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IAutenticacionDbContext, AutenticacionDbContext>();

        return container;
    }
}
```

**Note**: With this I get the same error:

```
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: Which Unity related nuget packages are you using?

Comment: Install-Package Unity.WebAPI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC and Web.API are using **two different dependency resolver infrastructure**.

Your problem is that you try to use the `Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver` also for the MVC controllers. To setup unity correctly follow the instructions below:

To make Unity work with MVC controllers the ones which derives from `Controller`

- install the [Unity.Mvc3](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc3/) nuget package
- setup the dependecy reolver with using `DependencyResolver.SetResolver`:

  ```
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
      new Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
  ```

To make Unity work with the Web.API controllers the ones which derives form `ApiController`

- install the [Unity.WebAPi](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/) nuget package
- set the dependency resolver with using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`:

  ```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
      new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
  ```

Comment: your solution solved my problem, but I saw this link "http://netmvc.blogspot.com.ar/2012/04/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html" and then I removed the packets "Unity.Mvc3" and "Unity.WebAPI", then I reinstalled again, and finally it worked rigth. I just wanted to comment that it is complete the solution